# Gmail failing to accept TLS

Tags: ssl, email, postfix, gmail, starttls

I recently set up a postfix mail server. Testing it with other domains, everything seems to work well.

However, when my server tries to send messages to gmail, they are marked as spam, with the red padlock and note `rr.com did not encrypt this message`

(rr.com is not my domain. However, the above is *exactly* what gmail says)

After forcing tls, I find that my server is unable to send messages to gmail at all. Logs state that
`(TLS is required, but was not offered by host alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.96.26])`

Wait, what? Gmail certainly offers TLS!

What's happening here?

**`postconf -n`**

```
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_template_file = /etc/postfix/bounce.cf
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/maps/canonical
command_directory = /usr/bin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 104857600
mydestination = $myhostname
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $myhostname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/cert.pem
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname, nexthop, dot-nexthop
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_sender_login_mismatch,
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !TLSv1 !SSLv2 !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/maps/valiases
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/maps/vmailbox-domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/maps/vmailbox-users
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Comment: Maybe your server is behind some firewall which MITM the SMTP dialog to filter out STARTTLS support Do a packet capture on the traffic to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Steffen is right! Once I disabled SMTP inspection on my firewall, everything passed through perfectly.